# Conditional Dynamic Block for private IP on NIC that accepts null value in Azure

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a VM module that deploys a linux VM. On the NIC resource, I have variables for private and public IPs in an ip_configuration block and it works great as is.

I have a new requirement from a team using that module to support adding a large number of additional private IPs to be assigned to that same NIC. I'm trying to add an additional ip_configuration block with a dynamic for_each loop to create these additional IPs that must also run successfully with no additional IPs when they aren't necessary.

Coding the loop to add the IPs was no issue. The problem I'm running into is that the loop will not accept a null or empty value, so it will not run successfully without additional IPs being configured.

Here's an example of what I've got:

```
variable additional_private_ips {
  type        = any
  default     = null
  description = "List of additional Private IPs to attach to the VM's NIC."
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                          = "nic-${var.vm_name}"
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  dns_servers                   = var.dns_servers
  enable_accelerated_networking = var.enable_accelerated_networking

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig-${var.vm_name}"
    primary                       = true
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = var.private_ip_address_allocation_type
    private_ip_address            = var.private_ip_address_allocation_type == "Static" ? var.private_ip_address : null
    public_ip_address_id          = var.enable_public_ip_address == true ? element(concat(azurerm_public_ip.pip[*].id, [""]), 0) : null
  }

  dynamic "ip_configuration" {
    for_each = var.additional_private_ips

    content {
      name                          = lookup(ip_configuration.value, "name", null)
      subnet_id                     = var.additional_private_ips != null ? var.subnet_id : null
      private_ip_address_allocation = lookup(ip_configuration.value, "private_ip_address_allocation", var.additional_private_ips != null ? "Static" : null)
      private_ip_address            = lookup(ip_configuration.value, "private_ip_address", null)
    }
  }
}
```

error message:

```
Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value
│
│   on .terraform\modules\vm\vm.tf line 38, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic":
│   38:     for_each = var.additional_private_ips
│     │ var.additional_private_ips is null
│
│ Cannot use a null value in for_each.
```

Comment: using an empty array as the default value should solve this.

Comment: That’s what I thought, too. It doesn’t. That’s the basis of this post. The error above is the error I get when the array is either empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to test this in azure.But tried with aws security groups as like below and it worked for me

```
variable "sg_bastion_security_rules" {
default = null
}

resource "aws_security_group" "mongo-bastion-sg" {
  vpc_id   = var.vpc-id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.sg_bastion_security_rules == null ? [] : var.sg_bastion_security_rules
    content {
      description = ingress.value.description
      from_port   = ingress.value.from_port
      to_port     = ingress.value.to_port
      protocol    = ingress.value.protocol
      cidr_blocks = ingress.value.cidr_blocks
    }
  }
}
```

Terraform plan output as below

$ terraform plan

```
provider.aws.region
  The region where AWS operations will take place. Examples
  are us-east-1, us-west-2, etc.

  Enter a value: us-west-2


Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

# aws_security_group.mongo-bastion-sg will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group" "mongo-bastion-sg" {
      + arn                    = (known after apply)
      + description            = "Managed by Terraform"
      + egress                 = (known after apply)
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + ingress                = (known after apply)
      + name                   = (known after apply)
      + name_prefix            = (known after apply)
      + owner_id               = (known after apply)
      + revoke_rules_on_delete = false
      + tags_all               = (known after apply)
      + vpc_id                 = "123456"
    }
```

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.